# AFKPageflipper iOS 7 issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, flipboard, flipview

I have implemented AFKPageflipper for page flip action as like flip board app.But flip animation was not working properly on iOS 7 as expected.But its working fine on below version.
I am wondering about this issue.Can anyone please suggest me solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code on `AFKPageFlipper.m` according to the instructions here `https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper/issues/28`

I got it working with the following change:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)])
  [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
else // iOS 6
  [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```